# Create a link dynamically, click it and destroy it, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made some brackets for a tournament and I'm using Owl carousel to serve videos on each clicked match.

The problem I've been trying to solve is this: Create a link after each click on a match, have this link clicked (by itself) which will, in turn, activate a certain slide in the carousel. Unfortunately that's the only way this could be made to work, because the Owl carousel needs links for callbacks. It's something like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwFMn/9/ except that in my example I have the brackets loaded below.

Now (after searching for a solution and trying every method suggested here in other questions on SO) I couldn't find a way to get a link which was appended to a div to be clicked too immediately after being created. What I get is this: on clicking a match, a link is created which needs to be clicked separately to get the behaviour I described above.

I have tried all the methods which use

`on('click', selector-to-your-element , function() { ... });`

as well as simply:

`$('.something').click();`

as well as other methods using `live` and `delegate`. None of the solutions proposed on other similar questions on SO worked. It seems as if at the time when the click event is triggered jQuery doesn't find the link it has just created to click it, so the link only works after you click it manualy.

The problem is I need this to not only work on one single click but also I need this link to get destroyed after it automatically gets clicked. I'm not even sure this is possible with jQuery. I'm curious if anyone has a working solution for this.

Comment: For "automatically" clicking it, use the `.trigger('click')` method.

Comment: No need to do all that ... the owl api has a method `owl.goTo(x)` which will go to target slide

Comment: @charlietfl -- Yes, but Owl needs those links to already exist somewhere, or at least be created to be clicked, as far as I know. In fact, I took the callbacks example from their documentation. You can see that example in the fiddle I posted. Are you saying there is another way to get the same behaviour without using callbacks and URLhashListeners?

Comment: Look at the public methods in the api docs

Comment: @charlietfl Is goTo() supported in version 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger the href with a javascript click event. You need to do something like this:

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
   location.href=$(this).attr('href'); 
});

$("[href=#seven]").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Does that open a new tab in the browser? I think I've tried something similar at some point and it was opening a new tab.

Comment: It shouldn't. It should just go to the anchor point. Add the code to the end of you fiddle script. It should slide to the seven spot.